# while running mvn it throws error of java home not defined

Tags: java, maven

I have mvn and java installed in my machine.

Still it throws `JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.`:

```
mvn clean compile install -DskipTests
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java

ijaz@ijaz20:~/codebase/central-repo/core-container$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
ijaz@ijaz20:~/codebase/central-repo/core-container$
```

Comment: Let's start with the obvious: do you or do you not have the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` defined?

Comment: please see my last statement. java -version shows java present

Comment: Please review my question: do you have the *environment variable* `JAVA_HOME` defined?

Comment: The fact that `java -version` runs does not mean you have `JAVA_HOME` defined. What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` give you?

Comment: it says /opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/

Comment: How about `ls $JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your java version:
The JAVA_HOME is set to `/opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/`

And if you rung java --version you get the version `1.7.0_60`

1.7.0_65 is not equals 1.7.0_60

So you have to change your JAVA_HOME variable.

Answer (score 0):

`JAVA_HOME` is currently set, or defaulting, to `/opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java`, which is not correct, tha's the location of the java binary, not the installation.

Try setting JAVA_HOME to the actual java home:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/"
```

Comment: echo JAVA_HOME says /opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/

Comment: If JAVA_HOME was really set as you say, then the command tried to be executed would show up as `/opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java/bin/java`.

Comment: ijaz@ijaz20:/opt/software$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/
ijaz@ijaz20:/opt/software$

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$ which java
```

If that doesn't give you

```
/opt/software/jdk1.7.0_65/bin/java
```

then your JAVA_HOME is set improperly. Specifically, it appears that you currently have JDK 7 Update 60 installed, but JAVA_HOME is pointing to a non-existent JDK 7 Update 65. Fix your JAVA_HOME accordingly.

`which java` could also give you a location which has a *symbolic link* to the real location of the executable; you can check that with

```
$ ls -l `which java`
```

to see where it's pointing to.

Comment: it says like below

ijaz@ijaz20:/opt/software$ ls -l `which java`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jul 18 14:40 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java

Comment: Then apply this again: `ls -l /etc/alternatives/java`.